# What could be reason of the error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' inside Ember Data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

After Ember release new version 3.6.0 I started to get the error in console:

> rsvp.js:24 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at WeakMap.get ()
>       at getCacheFor (metal.js:25)
>       at ComputedProperty.get (metal.js:2350)
>       at Array.CPGETTER_FUNCTION [as []] (metal.js:752)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:261)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:282)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:282)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:282)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:282)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.jQuery.fn.extend (jquery.js:282)

I figured out that reason of it `store.query` request in `init` in one of my components:

```
this.get('store').query('user', { 'filter': { 'type': '1', 'gender': 'male' } }).then(tutors => {
    this.set("tutors", tutors);
});
```

How to figure out a reason why I started to get this error?

Comment: I'm guessing you have a circular reference somewhere in your code. Do you have a model that has another model in it that contains the original by any chance?

Comment: @Liam, in my model `User` I have only like `posts: DS.hasMany('post', {
        inverse: 'user'
    }),`

Comment: @Dmitro did you check your computed properties at all? Look at the stack trace you provided: `rsvp.js:24 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at WeakMap.get () at getCacheFor (metal.js:25) at ComputedProperty.get (metal.js:2350) at ` I would have checked the `CP`s I had; I think your suspicions regarding the `store query` might not be true.

Comment: Which version of ember and ember-data are you using? I guess ember 3.6 and ember data 3.5.x? Did you have seen this issue also on an older version of ember? Are you able to provide a simple reproduction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may be this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/17190

This has not been fixed in Ember 3.6. You may need to continue using Ember 3.5 or to apply the workaround in this comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/17190#issuecomment-440208573

Comment: [Ember 3.7.0-beta.2](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v3.7.0-beta.2) contains this fix. I am seeing that same error for other tests in our application even after applying the patch. I will update my comment once finding a fix.