# ember install ember-modifier-manager-polyfill ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: ember.js, polyfills

After install addon: `ember install ember-modifier-manager-polyfill`
Got failed testing suite on CI only (if run each particular test alone locally - test passed)

Here is the issue in status open about it:
https://github.com/ember-polyfills/ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill/issues/110
but in my case I have no similar case in templates:

```
{{#each questions as |question|}}
  {{component question.componentName question=question}}
{{/each}}
```

So, it's something different... coz the failed are different tests (Integration/Acceptance) in different parts of the system

Notes:

```
ember-source: 2.18.2
ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill: 2.0.2
jquery: 3.5.1
ember-modifier-manager-polyfill: 1.2.0
```

it's not a duplicate of this:
[What could be reason of the error 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' inside Ember Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708454/what-could-be-reason-of-the-error-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-inside-embe)
or this:
[Ember Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242985/ember-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)
but the error with the same message

Output example:

```
stack: >
                at DOMAssertions.exists (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/test-support.js:24416:16)
                at DOMAssertions.exists (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/test-support.js:24737:18)
                at Object._callee$ (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/tests.js:141899:45)
                at tryCatch (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6235:40)
                at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6509:22)
                at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:6268:21)


browser log: |
            ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72303:51)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
                at CurlyComponentManager.manager.didCreateElement (http://0.0.0.0:4200/assets/vendor.js:72304:45)
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: If I got it right the test suite is failing on CI but not locally. Two common reasons: 1. Different node versions. 2. Different version of dependencs. To debug I would start with: Check that the node version used on CI is supported by `ember-modifier-manager-polyfill` and other addons used. Maybe try using the same node version on CI as locally to see if it passes. Do you lock down your dependencies using `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json` and is that one committed? Are you using same package manager locally and on CI? Did you verified that it respects the lockfile when installing on CI?

Comment: sure, the packager, yarn.lock required for sure, only the difference in run `ember tests` locally and `ember exam` on CI, and yeah - it is reproducible locally by ember exam, thanks to raising it, I've rechecked, but I still do not understand the reasons

Comment: Do I get it right that you can reproduce the error both locally as well as on CI if executing the test suite with `ember exam` instead of `ember test`?

Comment: @jelhan omg, sorry for the huge delay, somehow I've missed your comment. Yes, on local by `CI=true ember exam --split=32 --partition=12 --parallel` I got failed tests with `ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` reason, but on `ember test --filter="Title'S of failed test'S on CI"` run, I have all tests passed.

Comment: @jelhan btw, I got bump of ember-source to 2.16.4 but still have this issue

Comment: the issue still persist on 2.18.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in our project by rewritten tests codebase with modern syntax because the tests codebase was in-migration state: some tests were in legacy but some were with modern syntax.

So, to resolve - Deprecate tests with `moduleFor...` , for example `moduleForAcceptance`.

Mentioned here:
https://github.com/ember-polyfills/ember-angle-bracket-invocation-polyfill/issues/110#issuecomment-815088157